# remember me in laravel 5

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

my remember me functionality is not correctly working, Can any one help me with this..............

my problem is " when the user is logged in using remember me a cookie is being created but when he logs out the cookie is destroyed... that means when he wants to login again he has to remember his user name and password"

my Controller.php

```
$remember   = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;
if (\Auth::attempt('frontendUsers', array('cardno'    => Input::get('cardno'),'password'  => Input::get('password')), $remember)) 
                { 
...........................
}
```

my ajax

```
$("#loginform").submit(function(){

        var cardno       = $("#cardno").val();
        var password     = $("#pass").val();
        var catagory_id  = $("#catagory_id").val();

        var remember     = $("input[name = 'remember']:checked").length;

        $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url("postlogin") }}',

                dataType: 'json',

                type: 'post',

                data: {cardno:cardno,password:password,catagory_id:catagory_id,remember:remember},

                success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
.................
}
error:function(data){

                },
            });
            return false;
});
```

Comment: The cookie being destroyed has nothing to do with the `cardno` and `password` fields not being filled automatically by the browser.

Comment: what to do so that when remember me is checked the browser automatically fills the feilds?

Comment: This is related to the browser settings of the user. The user will be prompted for the credentials to be remembered or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$remember   = ($request->has('remember')) ? true : false;
```

You should not call 'has' statically.

Instead of

```
Input::has()
```

Let it be

```
$request->has()
```